# Combining (& Cutting?) multiple chandelier wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

My wife bought this chandelier online, and it came with a very brief instruction manual (in Chinese).

[image]

I’ve installed chandeliers before and they’ve been simple enough, but I got a bit stuck when I saw the 5 separate sets of 2 wires (black and brown) for each light, and even more so when I saw that were each loops, rather than stripped/prepared wires.

[image]

How would I go about connecting these to the main wire?  I’ve thought about cutting each one and trying to reach the center one, but they honestly seem too short?

Lastly, I’ve got some additional parts that I honestly don’t understand, and aren’t showing the manual.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Loops don't make sense because it costs more to make a loop.  Did you try tugging on the ends to see if there's a free end just tucked under?

Comment: The parts look like anchor bolts, to attach to drywall/cement.  Good chance that only has a CE label and is not allowed to be used in US/CAN homes.

Comment: I feel dumb now.  I had pulled on the wire but apparently the wrong end because the other end did end up coming out….

Comment: <pedantry> the bolt thingies are concrete anchors, not drywall </pedantry>

Comment: @crip659 how can I verify if this can be used in US homes?

Comment: Would need an UL/CSA label on it.  Because the instructions are only in Chinese, which UL also inspects, besides safety, the likely chance is close to zero.  Any insurance claim would likely be denied, if this was found in the home.

Comment: Use in USA:  are the lamps replaceable with 120V ones?  if not getting a 220V circuit to the location where you want to install it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: I sure hope that's an LED fixture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my earlier comment:

Loops don't make sense because it costs more to make a loop. Try tugging on the ends to see if there's a free end just tucked under.

I'm unsure about the bolts.  It looks like there's a few of them securing the mounting bracket at the top of the page, but I'm not seeing how it would work with only 3 of them.

Answer (score 2):

The proper thing to do with "electrical items that only have instructions in Chinese" if you are not in China is to return them whence they came before you burn your house down, get electrocuted, or otherwise discover the hard way why having electrical items **listed** by  a **Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory** is essential for safety.

I very much doubt this one is, since the instructions are part of the listing process.